# Data Added twice in to the database using JTable java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i am trying to add my all data in the Jtable to the mysql database. but data added successfully. but Data Added twice into the database. I attached the screenshot below of database table how record added 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC8Df.jpg)

**this is the code which i tried**

```
try{      

  int rows=jTable1.getRowCount();
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
  java.sql.Connection  con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javasales","root",""); 
  con1.setAutoCommit(false);
  String queryco = "Insert into sales_product(product,price) values (?,?)";    
  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) con1.prepareStatement(queryco,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
  for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
  {         
    String product = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0);
    String price = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);       
    preparedStmt.setString(1, product);
    preparedStmt.setString(2, price);
    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet generatedKeyResult = preparedStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
     preparedStmt.addBatch();

    preparedStmt.executeBatch();
    con1.commit();       
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Save");    
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your code you are iterating each row one by one and on every iteration you are executing both :

```
preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
preparedStmt.executeBatch();
```

That's why same row has been inserted twice. 
You can go with below solutions to avoid multiple insertion.

1. Only use `preparedStmt.executeUpdate();` within the loop and remove     `preparedStmt.executeBatch();`

   ```
   preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
       ResultSet generatedKeyResult = preparedStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
   //     preparedStmt.addBatch();
     //  preparedStmt.executeBatch();
       con1.commit();       
     }
   ```
2. Don't use `preparedStmt.executeUpdate();` and move `preparedStmt.executeBatch();` outside of loop.

   ```
   //preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
   //ResultSet generatedKeyResult = preparedStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    preparedStmt.addBatch();
   }
   preparedStmt.executeBatch();
   con1.commit();
   ```

Comment: it is working now. i have removed  this lines preparedStmt.addBatch();
  //  preparedStmt.executeBatch();

Comment: Be aware that the generated keys support with batch execution is not required by JDBC (so its driver-specific if it works or not), and in that case `getGeneratedKeys` would need to be moved out of the loop as well.